# im using python pandas to extract some data(page titles) but outputs are not in the same order as the URLs i put in the code

Tags: python, excel, pandas, beautifulsoup

So I Wrote the code and ran it and got the .xlsx file but the output is not as the same order of the Url list i put in the code.

```
#importing the libraries
import re
import lxml
import  chardet
from os import truncate
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import multiprocessing
import requests
import pandas as pd
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import numpy as np

urls = list(('https://isabad.com/advanced-professional-email-templates-opencart-extension' ,
'https://isabad.com/seo-basic-pack-opencart-extension',
'https://isabad.com/x-shipping-pro',
'https://isabad.com/bot-blocker-opencart-extension',
'https://isabad.com/opencart-mobile-application'
))

dit = {}
user_agent = UserAgent()
for url in urls:
        data = requests.get(url, headers={"user-agent": user_agent.chrome})
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.content, "lxml")
        dit[url] = soup.find_all("title")
        ex = pd.DataFrame({"title": dit ,})
        print(ex)
        ex.to_excel('sasa.xlsx', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

How Can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `set` data structure for storing the list of URLs and the `set` data structure in python is an unordered data structure. To have the output in the same order, you should store the URLs in `list` data structure as follows:

```
urls = [
  'https://www.sample.com/search/category-mobile/' ,
  'https://www.sample.com/search/category-tablet-ebook-reader',
  'https://www.sample.com/search/category-laptop/',
  'https://www.sample.com/search/category-computer-parts/',
  'https://www.sample.com/search/category-office-machines/'
]
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but I did what you said, and again the same result. is there any errors in the code?

Comment: @dadashzadeh well, I see that for each URL you are updating the same dictionary named `dit`. I think you should put that part outside the code. Also, if you assign some data to the dictionary it will also lose the order. I would suggest that you start with an empty data frame outside the loop and then keep appending the data in the loop and then after the loop you store it in excel file.

Answer (score 1):

use a `list` so the results would be in the same order that you defined.

```
urls = ['https://www.sample.com/search/category-mobile/' ,
'https://www.sample.com/search/category-tablet-ebook-reader',
'https://www.sample.com/search/category-laptop/',
'https://www.sample.com/search/category-computer-parts/',
'https://www.sample.com/search/category-office-machines/'
]
```

[image]

Comment: I used your code and I saw it corrected after I used list. are u sure? motmaeni refigh?

Comment: Yes i used " [] " and even " list(()) " . and again the same result as before.

Comment: It's weird maybe you should restart your kernel and run your code again. I uploaded a picture which shows it works fine for me. Check out my edited answer.

Comment: you just printed the urls. but when i run the whole cod and get the data from urls and i want to print the data as the same order of the origin urls. it scramles. not the same order.

Comment: i edited the code and i used real urls that im using. please copy the whole code and run it. and take a look at the final excel file . and compare the urls and the ouputs order and see what im saying.